# How to pass variable to a Jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery, and I'm trying to use a function found on the internet that shows a tooltip when you over a HTML element.

This is the function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#my-tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span>This text is in bold case !</span>')
   });
});
</script>

<img src="img.jpg" id="my-tooltip">
```

Let's say that I want to apply this function to many elements on the page, for example:

```
  <img src="img1.jpg" id="my-tooltip1">
  <img src="img2.jpg" id="my-tooltip2">
  <img src="img3.jpg" id="my-tooltip3">
```

How should I edit the the function? I can't do

```
<img src="img.jpg1" id="my-tooltip1" onmouseover="javascript:functionName('tooltip1')" onmouseout="javascript:functionName('tooltip1')">
```

since ths function  will not work the way it works now.

Thank you

Comment: Different messages according to the different element.

Comment: Use class (.) identifiers instead of id (#) identifiers

Comment: Its documented http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#getting-started

Comment: I was wrong, he IS doing it in right way, it's just other way than it's usual (via html `title` attribute).

Comment: OP knows that, he copied the html in the question from there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already suggested, use a CSS class to select your tooltip-enabled elements.

The text of the tooltip can be parametrized with a custom `data-` attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tooltip').each(function() {
    $(this).tooltipster({
      content: $(this).attr("data-tooltip")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  cursor: help;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
.tooltipster-base {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.js"></script>
<img class="tooltip" data-tooltip="I am a unicorn!" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e3/ab/d2/e3abd2c3b64151e4c1dfe59e5a2227dc.jpg">
<img class="tooltip" data-tooltip="Look at me!" src="http://cartoon-animals.disneyimage.com/_/rsrc/1367525874171/cartoon-unicorn-clipart/Unicorn-Clipart_7.png">
<img class="tooltip" data-tooltip="I poop rainbows" src="http://grid.turtlespeak.net/upload/LMo6pu2bZ3pYC5QU/iH3dtwYF1tOwoBd8/un1.png">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use "class" instead of "id",  :

```
  <img src="img1.jpg" class="my-tooltip">
  <img src="img2.jpg" class="my-tooltip">
  <img src="img3.jpg" class="my-tooltip">
```

Your script will be like this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.my-tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span>This text is in bold case !</span>')
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: See the Tinmar note above.

Comment: You'll get the same message for each img. Not asked by OP

Comment: You can just parametize the span. `<span data-tooltip="tooltip-text">` and use that in your jquery: `$().data('tooltip')`

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to identify multiple elements which should behave in a similar manner:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.my-tooltip').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span>This text is in bold case !</span>')
   });
});
</script>

<img src="img.jpg" class="my-tooltip">
```

Notice I changed the selector to $('.my-tooltip')...

And then change the id attribute on the images to 'class'.

Comment: You'll get the same message for each img. Not asked by OP

Comment: You can just parametize the span. `<span data-tooltip="tooltip-text">` and use that in your jquery: `$().data('tooltip')`

Comment: @Rolf indeed. Didnt see his comment, only the OP.

Answer (score -1):

You can use html encoding in the title attribute, as described on the Getting Started page of tooltipster, or you can call tooltipster once for each image and assign a different text.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#my-tooltip1').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span>You can tip me</span>')
   });
   $('#my-tooltip2').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span>I would like to go boldly</span>')
   });
   $('#my-tooltip3').tooltipster({
        content: $('<span>Hello there</span>')
   });
});
```

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Use classes and define  the tooltip within the image tag.

Comment: No. The purposes of id and class:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2 
and 
https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute